# google drive V3 file list api is not returning emailaddress field in lastModifyingUser structure

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using a service account to execute google drive file list API with query fields `nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, mimeType, lastModifyingUser)` for our shared google drive.

I get all other fields in response. But in lastModifyingUser structure, I just get these fields

```
"lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "XYZ",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "100"
   }
```

I am not getting emailAddress field in above structure.

But when I use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list to make exactly same query and fields, I get

```
"lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "XYZ",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "100",
    "emailAddress": "XYZ@XYZ.com"
   }
```

Any idea why am I not getting emailAddress field with drive SDK API calls in response?

Comment: What is `drive sdk API calls` of `Can anybody please tell me why am I not getting emailAddress field with drive sdk API calls in response?`?

Comment: So basically you could get this data unless you were using service accounts right? Have you granted [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) for your service account?

Comment: no have not granted DWD. But service account has EDITOR role on files

Comment: Hi ! Could you please try this request after you have granted domain-wide delegation to your service account? According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) ```lastModifyingUser.emailAddress: The email address of the user. This may not be present in certain contexts if the user has not made their email address visible to the requester``` which might explain why you cannot see it even if you have the editor role on the file (and thus you would need admin level access).